# Timer Countdown mvc 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to make timer countdown who will showing how much time has left

example: Time Left: 04:15:20  and on and on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) is a jQuery plugin which gives you such a timer.  There are quite a few [similar examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+countdown) which should help.